# Simple Join

Tags: c#, subsonic

This question is about subsonic

I am trying to build a select query HAVING joins in it using subsonic.

For Example if I want to extract data from 3 tables then how I will be able to do it in Subsonic.
Lets say if I have a TSQL given below then How I will be able to translate this into Subsonic?

```
Select la.LoanAppId, ci.FirstName, ci.LastName, la.ApplicationDateSubmitted, 
       la.LoanAmount, la.DueDate, lkUpD.Col1Value
from LoanApplication la, ContactInfo ci, LookUpDetails lkUpD
where la.UserId = ci.UserId
and la.StatusId =   lkUpD.LookUpDetailId
```

Please Reply

Answer (score 0):

```
SubSonic.SqlQuery q = new Select(
     LoanApplication.LoanAppId, ContactInfo.FirstNa, [etc])
    .From(LoanApplication.Schema)
    .InnerJoin(ContactInfo.Schema)
    .InnerJoin(LookUpDetails.Schema);
```

if all the inner joins are natural (else, you need to add more `.InnerJoin` calls to specify the inner-join conditions).